# The canvas isn't showing up in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So, I'm trying to include a drawing page in my website, and P5.js is probably the simplest way I know how, because it's similar to Processing.js, and I learned that from Khan Academy and all that.
But for some reason, the canvas isn't showing up, and the thing is, there are no error messages, AND and, it works on the P5.js website editor.

Admittedly, I haven't tried anything more than copy-pasting the code into the script tag, so it might be incredibly obvious.
Here's the script tag:

```html
    <script src="lib/p5.js">
    function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255, 255, 255);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  if(mouseIsPressed){
    fill(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
    
    
  }
}
    </script>
```

(The only thing in the lib folder is p5.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a separate `<script>` tag for your library import, and your sketch javascript. HTML does not support `<script>` tags that have a `src` and inline content.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
      background(200);
      noStroke();
    }

    function draw() {
      if (mouseIsPressed) {
        fill(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);


      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Example:
</body>
```